# Angular Row not displaying using Ng-for to display NgTemplate

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I'm using an ngFor in a container to display template rows corresponding to the type, instead of hardcoding the whole form. However I can't get any rows to display. I've tried making an ngif and
forcing everything to display.

HTML

```
 <ng-container
    *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column)"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"
  ></ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="displayAsRow">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns">
    <c-form-row [title]="column.title" [description]="column.description">
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column)" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"></ng-container>
    </c-form-row>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

HTML example of ng-template by type

```
    <ng-template #text let-column>
  <div *cHasRole="checkPermissions(column.permissions)" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content col-3 mb-3">
    <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{ 'col-11': column?.description }" appearance="outline" stateChange="onFieldChange(column)">
      <mat-label>{{ column.title | translate }} {{ column.validation && column.validation.required ? ' *' : '' }}</mat-label>
      <input matInput [formControlName]="column.field" [readonly]="checkColumnReadOnly(column)" />
      <mat-hint *ngIf="column.hintLabel">{{ column.hintLabel }}</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkValidationErrors(column, 'required')">
        {{ util.formatFormErrorMsg(column.title, 'required') }}
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkValidationErrors(column, 'pattern')">
        {{ util.formatFormErrorMsg(column.title, 'pattern') }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <h5 *ngIf="column?.description" class="cursor-pointer col-1 pl-0" [ngbTooltip]="column.description" placement="right-center">
      <i class="far fa-info-circle text-info"></i>
    </h5>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Method that is returning the string:

```
getColumnInputType(column: any): string {
  if (column.type.toLowerCase() === 'datetime' || column.type.toLowerCase() === 'date' || column.type.toLowerCase() == 'boolean') {
    return column.type.toLowerCase();
  }
  return column.inputMetaData.inputType.toLowerCase();
}
```

[image: Error in console]

Comment: What does `getColumnInputType` return?

Comment: It returns a string that will match the value of the template name

Comment: It needs to return a `TemplateRef`! https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: @AndreiTătar How am I able to return a TemplateRef from a method, I have included the method that returns the string above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getColumnInputType` returns a string but the `ng-container` `ngTemplateOutlet` input expects a `TemplateRef`.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

#### 1. Either send the template reference types to the function that is checking the type:

```
getColumnInputType(column: any, textTemplate: TemplateRef): TemplateRef {
  if (column.type === 'text') {
    return textTemplate;
  }

  //TODO: what if you don't have a template for the given type
}
```

so in your HTML you can do something like:

```
<ng-container
  *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column, text)"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"
>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #text let-column>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

#### 2. Capture the references by their name in the component:

```
@ViewChild('text') textTemplate: TemplateRef;

getColumnInputType(column: any): TemplateRef {
  if (column.type === 'text') {
    return this.textTemplate;
  }

  //TODO: what if you don't have a template for the given type
}
```

and in the HTML:

```
<ng-container
  *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column)"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"
>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #text let-column>
  ...
</ng-template>
```